# Is it possible to change the size of a navigation bar text

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar on my IOS app. And I am trying to change the navigation bar text for IPADs however although I can change the navigation bar font typeface I cannot change the font size. Please can someone let me know where I have gone wrong. Please find the code below:

```
if ([self isIPAD ])
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil, [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:28], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
}
else
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
}
```

Comment: Just remove the extra "nil" you have in attritube for ipad condition. It's     NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, **nil**(remove this), [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:28], NSFontAttributeName, nil];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the size of the font can be adapted. you have a typo. You have to remove the nil in the middle of the dictionary.

I'd advise you to use the objC literal syntax to 'catch' those errors earlier. This syntax is much stricter:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:28]};
```

(NOTE also the size of the bar is hardcoded so your font cannot grow indefinitely.)